# Memory leak in Ada.Strings.Unbounded ?

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, ada

I have a curious memory leak, it seems that the library function to_unbounded_string is leaking!

Code snippets:

```
procedure Parse (Str    : in     String;
```

... do stuff...

```
declare
   New_Element : constant Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String :=
     Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String (Str); -- this leaks
begin
```

valgrind output:

```
==6009== 10,276 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 153 of 153
==6009==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==6009==    by 0x42703B8: __gnat_malloc (in /usr/lib/libgnat-4.4.so.1)
==6009==    by 0x4269480: system__secondary_stack__ss_allocate (in /usr/lib/libgnat-4.4.so.1)
==6009==    by 0x414929B: ada__strings__unbounded__to_unbounded_string (in /usr/lib/libgnat-4.4.so.1)
==6009==    by 0x80F8AD4: syntax__parser__dash_parser__parseXn (token_parser_g.adb:35)
```

Where token_parser_g.adb:35 is listed above as the "-- this leaks" line.

Other info: Gnatmake version 4.4.5. gcc version 4.4 valgrind version valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian, valgrind options -v --leak-check=full --read-var-info=yes --show-reachable=no

Any help or insights appreciated,

NWS.

Comment: Off-topic, but IMHO there's a very good chance you don't need to be using `Unbounded_String`s here at all. The *Ada-way* of doing string manipulation is to make creative use of scoping and functions to build perfectly-sized constant strings when and where you need them. About the only time you need dynamicly-sized strings is for buffers when performing textual I/O inputs.

Comment: @T.E.D. I am doing exactly that! -parsing dynamically sized text input, that is. I do much prefer to use the exact string when possible :)

Comment: Can you provide a small compilable source code that produces the error? I can't come up with one - no leaks here. (GNAT Pro 6.3.1, valgrind-3.3.1, --read-var-info no valid parameter)

Comment: @oenone In short, No. all the 'short programs' using this method produce no error leak. It only happens when the memory footprint is larger. (and im not posting 8k+ lines of code!) This has also led me to the conclusion that Vlad is most likely right, and its not really a leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valgrind clearly says that there is **possibly** a memory leak. It doesn't necessarily mean there is one. For example, if first call to that function allocates a pool of memory that is re-used during the life time of the program but is never freed, Valgrind will report it as a possible memory leak, even though it is not, as this is a common practice and memory will be returned to OS upon process termination.

Now, if you think that there is a memory leak for real, call this function in a loop, and see it memory continues to grow. If it does - file a bug report or even better, try to find and fix the leak and send a patch along with a bug report.

Hope it helps.

Comment: From The Valgrind manual :"you should attempt to ensure your programs do not have any definitely lost or possibly lost blocks at exit." So until further notice i will consider it a leak, although your note about it maybe growing if it is genuine is worth investigating. Thanks. NWS.

Comment: @NWS: Long story short. It is technically a memory leak, but if you get down to earth and focus on what really matters - it is not, even if Valgrind developers think otherwise. But in either case it must be reported, which is being done here, because it __could__ be a real leak. So if you suspect it to be real growing leak, then debug it.

Comment: even valgrind doesnt have a crystal globe ;)

Comment: @Vlad - Correct, it doesnt grow when called repeatedly :)

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say that the Unbounded_String facility you are using is doing some kind of lazy deallocation to prevent a lot of unnessecary work (eg: if you have that declare block or `Parse` routine of yours in a loop). Since you are using Gnat, you could check the sources to see for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Was trying to keep this to comments, but what I was saying got too long and started to need formatting.

In Ada string objects are generally assumed to be perfectly-sized. The language provies functions to return the size and bounds of any string. Because of this, string handling in Ada is very different than C, and in fact more resembles how you'd do it in a functional language like Lisp.

But the basic principle is that, except in some very unusual situations, *if you find yourself using `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`, you are going about things the wrong way.*

The one case where you really can't get around using a variable-length string (or perhaps a buffer with a separate valid_length variable), is when reading strings as input from some external source. As you say, your parsing example is such a situation.

However, even here you should only have that situation on the initial buffer. Your call to your Parse routine *should* look something like this:

```
Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line (Buffer, Buffer_Len);
Parse (Buffer(Buffer'first..Buffer'first + Buffer_Len - 1));
```

Now inside the Parse routine you have a perfectly-sized constant Ada string to work with. If for some reason you need to pull out a subslice, you would do the following:

```
... --// Code to find start and end indices of my subslice
New_Element : constant String := Str(Element_Start...Element_End);
```

If you don't actually need to make a copy of that data for some reason though, you are better off just finding `Element_Start` and `Element_End` and working with a slice of the original string buffer. Eg:

```
if Str(Element_Start..Element_End) = "MyToken" then
```

I know this doesn't answer your question about Ada.Strings.Unbounded possibly leaking. But even if it doesn't leak, that code is relatively wasteful of machine resources (CPU and memory), and probably shouldn't be used for string manipulation unless you really **need** it.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know Ada at all, but how could dynamic string handling be using more than string with bounds, taking into account that both allocate memory etc.. it is C at the end of the day anyway. No?

Comment: @TED, I am considering using something other than unbounded strings, particularly as i have realised that i am tokenizing a string into a vector of little unnboundeds, and then reconverting into strings for further parsing :( ... Controlled_pointers to strings perhaps ?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - Ada.Strings.Unbounded uses the heap to dynamically allocate enough memory for the string you request. Not only is there a little memory overhead the heap requires to keep track of things, but there is a large CPU overhead involved in copying all your string data from its original location into the new area. Also, heap operations are non-deterministic, for those who care about such things (real-time programmers). Every time you resize your dynamic string for some reason, you could have to do all this again. It is convienent for some algorithims, but very inefficient.

Comment: @NWS - There is no reason whatsoever to be dealing with pointers. Using pointers in Ada is another thing that is required on occasion, but generally another sign that you are going about things wrong. Note that Ada will generally pass parameters that don't fit into a register (eg: your `Str` parameter to parse) **by reference**. Ada is not like C, where the stupid compiler will copy large amounts of parameter data on the stack when it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - FYI: The gnu Ada compiler does **not** translate Ada code into C code. It does use the "gcc" front end, but so do lots of other compilers. I know this confuses a lot of people, which is why the GCC folks now say it stands for `GNU Compiler Collection`, not `GNU C Compiler`.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Are bound strings scoped? If not, they have to use dynamically allocated memory as well. You can make memory allocations deterministic, btw (not `sbrk ()` tho).

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - There's an Ada.Strings.Bounded, that may or may not use heap memory depending on how its implemented. If you just declare a `String` object as I'm suggesting, that is scoped (iow: put on your task's stack, and popped back off when you exit its declared scope), just like any other declared variable. Its roughly akin to declaring an array with static bounds in C (eg: `char my_string[80];`), except that an Ada user can calculate the bounds with a variable or assigning from a string variable, and can always ask the compiler what the declared length of the array ended up being.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Yeah, if bound string is bound to function-scope then placing it on stack will be more efficient. Sort of like just an array of characters. Copying that thing would've been a nightmare compared to ref-counted dynamic string with copy-on-write.

Answer (score 1):

> Are bound[ed] strings scoped?

Expanding on @T.E.D.'s comments, [`Ada.Strings.Bounded`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-4.html) "objects should not be implemented by implicit pointers and dynamic allocation." Instead, the maximum size is fixed when the generic in instantiated. As an implmentation detail, GNAT uses a [discriminant](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-7.html) to specify the maximum size of the string and a record to store the current size & contents.

In contrast, [`Ada.Strings.Unbounded`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html) requires that "No storage associated with an `Unbounded_String` object shall be lost upon assignment or scope exit." As an implmentation detail, GNAT uses a buffered implementation derived from [`Ada.Finalization.Controlled`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-7-6.html). As a result, the memory used by an `Unbounded_String` may *appear* to be a leak until the object is finalized, as for example when the code returns to an enclosing scope.